# How do I add a column that marks one of each value?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, tableau-api

I'm joining two tables in SQL. I currently have the SQL as:

```
SELECT table1.ProjectName AS "Project Name",
  table1.ProjectCost AS "Project Cost",
  table2.ExpenseName AS "Expense Name",
  table2.ExpenseCost AS "Expense Cost"
  FROM TABLE1 table1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 table2
  ON table1.ProjectName = table2.ProjectName;
```

The result looks like:

```
Project Name    | Project Cost  | Expense Name  | Expense Cost
------------------------------------------------------------
Project 1   | 123456        | Labor     | 12365  
Project 1   | 123456        | Rent      | 120000  
Project 2   | 8421              | (null)    | (null)  
Project 3   | 987654        | Paper     | 1023  
Project 3   | 987654        | Pens      | 546
```

I want to add a row that marks one of each Project Name so that I can filter over it in Tableau and sum the projects costs.

EX:

```
Project Name    | Project Cost  | Expense Name  | Expense Cost  | Unique Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Project 1   | 123456        | Labor     | 12365     | Y  
Project 1   | 123456        | Rent      | 12000     | N  
Project 2   | 8421      | (null)    | (null)        | Y  
Project 3   | 987654        | Paper     | 1023      | Y  
Project 3   | 987654        | Pens      | 546       | N  
Project 3   | 987654        | Party     | 9856      | N
```

Comment: Which column is `Project Number`?

Comment: Sorry I meant project Name

Comment: Are you familiar with `EXISTS` clause?

Comment: @PM 77-1 No I'm not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suposse you can use the lag function, I actually asked this not a long time ago, I can share my question, maybe it helps you. But instead of selecting the value you could create a table temporal table and populate that column based on the lag function:

[SELECT Only one value per ID - SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105133/select-only-one-value-per-id-sql-server)

Comment: I realized I forgot to put my code in so I've added it. How do I use this with my code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use rank as well:

```
select t.* 
     , case when lag(project_name) over (partition by 1 order by project_name, rownum) = project_name then 'N' else 'Y' end n
     , case when rank() over (partition by project_name order by rownum) >  1 then 'N' else 'Y' end n
from join_result
```

Comment: I realized I forgot to put my code in so I've added it. How do I use this with my code?